# Mean of object variables in a python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python question.

I have a list (A) of numpy object arrays (B). I'd like to get the mean of one of the object variables for all the objects in the B array. Right now, I'm just parsing through the B array, summing the variable and dividing it by the number of objects in B. Is there a better or more pythonic way to do this?

It would also be great, if I could get the mean of all objects in the A list (i.e. all objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a numpy array, you can just call the `mean` method:

```
In [24]: import numpy as np

In [25]: b = np.arange(5)

In [26]: b
Out[26]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [27]: b.mean()
Out[27]: 2.0
```

If you have a list of numpy arrays, getting the mean of each numpy is just:

```
In [28]: A = [np.arange(i) for i in range(3, 6)]

In [29]: A
Out[29]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]

In [30]: for B in A: print B.mean()
1.0
1.5
2.0
```

Or, if you're trying to get the mean of all the elements (over all elements of B in A), use the `sum` method:

```
In [31]: sum(B.sum() for B in A) / sum(len(B) for B in A)
Out[31]: 1.5833333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing sounds fine for the object arrays, that's really the only way to get an average. As for the average of all the elements in A, just add each average as you iterate through the list, and then divide by the total number of objects in A

Comment: you'd need to add each item as you iterate through the list, then divide.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it all up in a list comprehension:

```
[sum(x)/len(x) for x in array_list]
```

If you wanted to get the mean of all the objects, you could do the following:

```
from __future__ import division
sums, lengths = zip(*[(sum(x),len(x)) for x in array_list])
mean = sum(sums) / sum(lengths)
# still can get averages for each object too
array_averages = [s/l for s,l in zip(sums,lengths)]
```

Just because I was confused about the syntax of unpacking a list into zip the first time, quick illustration:

```
>>> tuples = [(1,2,'a'), (3,4,'b'), (5,6,'c'), (7,8,'d')]
>>> print zip(*tuples)
[(1,3,5,7), (2,4,6,8), ('a','b','c','d')]
>>> a,b,c = zip(*tuples)
>>> print a
(1,3,5,7)
>>> print c
('a','b','c','d')
```